# Less than and Greater than symbols are converting to '->' on the browser

Tags: html, spring, jsp, special-characters, tiles

I am working on a spring mvc web application i have all the static text inside the jsp.

1. Using tiles to render the views
2. Declared `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the baselayout jsp
3. Add import on top of the jsp 
   "<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>"

I am so confused why the browser is converting the > and < symbols to wired direction symbols like

> -> and <-

This is the code snippet

```
<p>It's a white powder with > 90-95% degree of acetylation and a pH of 7.0-8.0</p>
```

I have also used the `&gt;` but no luck

Please help.

Comment: Please include the code thats becoming `-> and <-`.

Comment: When you say you tried `&gt`, but had "no luck", are you saying that `&gt` is also becoming `->`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes it converts to `->`

Comment: I found the root cause, it's the font(DIN) that I am importing in my css file is overriding it. I put the symbol inside a `<span>` and gave a css class with `font-family:Arial`